# take database user,pass,name and host info from user's and want to update a database column info

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I am new here and noob in programming.
I have created a script that can change a database column but now I want to take database login info from user's and the changed value from user's when they give all info correctly the script changed the database column info which was given by the user's.

Here is my login.html source code :

```
<html>
<center>

<form action="db.php" method="post">
DB Host:     <input type="text" name="host"><br>
DB Username: <input type="text" name="usr"><br>
DB Password: <input type="password" name="psw"><br>
DB Name:     <input type="text" name="dbname"><br><br><br>
Admin changed Username: <input type="text" name="admusr"><br>
Admin Changed Password: <input type="password" name="admpsw"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

and here is my db.php source code which can update database column info manually

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$dbname = "mydb";
$password = "1234";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$dbname");


$sql = "UPDATE admins SET user_login='admin1',user_pass='1234'  WHERE id=1";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();

?>
```

Is it possible to take value from user's and changed the database column info?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: its a terrible idea.  you should fully authenticate first and then provide the user with an interface where they can change details.  Doing the whole lot in one form is fraught with danger and extremely lazy.

Comment: I am doing this for another purpose

Comment: so you want to just update admin table with the info provided or you want to create a new config for database using the info provided?

Answer (score 1):

It's very bad idea... loads of security issues. But if you want to change it from received form values just change your query to this:

```
// escape received values
$usr = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['usr']);
$psw = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['psw']);

// use them in query
$sql = "UPDATE admins SET user_login='".$usr."',user_pass='".$psw."'  WHERE id=1";
```

You got more field which is user filling... I don't know your exact table structure. But if you want to use all of them just add received escaped values to your query:

```
// escape received values
$usr = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['usr']);
$psw = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['psw']);
$host = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['host']);
$dbname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['dbname']);
$admusr = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['admusr']);
$admpsw = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['admpsw']);

// use all of them in query depending on your table structure
$sql = "UPDATE admins SET user_login='".$usr."',user_pass='".$psw."'  WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: edited my answer. It was a procedural function name... now It's correct object function name real_escape_string

Comment: Please confirm correct answer if possible :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST` variable to retrieve data that user entered on login.html page

like in db.php for `$servername` and `$username` use

```
$servername = $_POST['host'];
$username = $_POST['usr'];
```

Comment: Bro I already try it but it's not working :( can you give the source code? Ajaykumartak

Comment: what error you are getting when you are using `$_POST`. Please post you db.php file code with updated code with `$_POST`.